# How is cached data validated with `reloadRevalidatingCacheData`?

Tags: ios, caching, urlcache

A `URLRequest` allows a cache option where cached data is revalidated with the origin by setting the option `.reloadRevalidatingCacheData`.

The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlrequest/cachepolicy/reloadrevalidatingcachedata) say:

> Use cache data if the origin source can validate it; otherwise, load
>   from the origin.

I assume the validation works by comparing hash values, but I did not find any reference to that.

How is the data validated?